# How can I create an instance of a model and validate it without saving to DB in Sails?

Tags: javascript, sails.js

I am wondering if and how I can do something like below in Sails. Basically, I am trying to handle complex validations - I have a Client model and ContactPerson model. The Client model has ContactPersons nested inside it, and I want to validate that they are all correct before continuing.

```
// client.js

module.exports = {

  attributes: {
    name: {
      type: 'string',
      required: true
    }
  },

  beforeValidation: function(values, cb) {
    values.contactPerson.forEach( function( person ) {
      var contactPerson = new sails.model.person( person );
      var results = contactPerson.validate();
      // If valid, continue
      // if not valid, invalidate the client Model (cause validationerror)
    });
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
// if not valid
if(err) return cb(err);
// if valid
cb();
```